# Return values by Yii db

Tags: php, database, arrays, yii

I have a following return value from Yii framework query, using the methods and classes built in Yii:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Developer
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Tester
        )

)
```

I would like to (using nothing but Yii), rearange this like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Developer
    [2] => Tester

)
```

Meaning, I will not group the results in a specific index of the array, and I will enlist them all in one array, AND my key/indexes will represent the value of ID field from my table, and value of those keys will be values from my "role" field from my table.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following method, defined [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml/#listData-detail):

`CHtml::listData($yourArray, 'id', 'title');`